# TinyMCE 4 & wp_editor multiple editor issue

Tags: tinymce, wp-editor

Just updated WordPress to new 3.9, new features are great, love them. Only got some issues with tinyMCE 4. I use `wp_editor` to create multiple tinyMCE editors with custom field.

Here is the code:

```
$tinymce_opt = array(
 'height'    => "250",
 'plugins'  => "nz_button, line, gap, slider_colorbox, icon_list, icons, font_size",
 'toolbar1' => "formatselect,fontselect, styleselect,|,bold,italic,underline,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,|,link,unlink,|,forecolor,removeformat,charmap,undo,redo",
 'toolbar2' => "nz_button, line, gap, slider_colorbox, icon_list, icons, font_size",
 'toolbar3' => ""
);

 $settings = array (
    'tinymce'       => $tinymce_opt
   );
  wp_editor( ${"layer_$i"}, "layer_$i", $settings);
```

Everything is fine. The problem is that it does not understand plugins (my custom shortcodes, that i created). Custom shortcodes work fine in regular wp editor, but in multiple wp_editor, it just does not find them.

In colsole i get error 404 can’t find

for example “line” shortcode

http://mywebsite.com/wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/line/plugin.min.js 404 (Not Found)

All my custom shortcodes are ignored, not found.

Does anyone know, how to tell tinyMCE + wp_editor to use custom shortcodes?

My custom shortcodes are located in my theme

P.S. It worked fine with old tinyMCE.

Comment: What is the actual value of `${"layer_$i"}`?

Comment: I don't have an answer for your question, but I wanted to point out that the text alignment button names have changed (possibly without warning... grrrr) in WordPress 3.9. You'll need to change "justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright" to "alignleft,aligncenter,alignright".

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.9 some parts of the settings for the original Editor are wrapped in a `self::first_init` condition. This includes the plugins filter for external tinymce plugins.
So, in a subsequent call for an editor, the filter won't run.

Solution: One can pass a tinymce settings array to the settings of wp_editor(), that's where I would start. Or enqueue the script manually as explained here:

[http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials:Creating_a_plugin](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Tutorials%3aCreating_a_plugin)